# Receive bytea with asp .net api

Tags: entity-framework, .net-4.0, edmx, postgresql-12, bytea

First of all, sorry for the probable English mistakes

I created a table in my postgresql database using the entity framework.

In edmx in the creation section I passed as bytea, however in the mapping I used binary (primitive type use is necessary).

```
<EntityType Name="styleexample">
      <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="id" />
      </Key>
      <Property Name="id" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
      <Property Name="example" Type="String" MaxLength="40" />
      <Property Name="example1" Type="Binary" />
      <Property Name="example2" Type="DateTime" />
</EntityType>

<EntityType Name="styleexample">
      <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="id" />
      </Key>
      <Property Name="id" Type="int4" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="example" Type="varchar" MaxLength="40" />
      <Property Name="example1" Type="bytea" />
      <Property Name="example2" Type="timestamp" />
</EntityType>
```

The table was created with the correct typing

[image: column]

In the entity I referenced the column as byte []

[image: entities]

In the column I inserted the base64 string of a png image, but in the service when I return the value is different from what I inserted

[image: execute the query in the database]

My response is also byte[]

It works. However, it returns the incorrect value. Is there a different way to do this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding to the service

```
var example1 = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(estilo.example1));
var example1Stream = example1 .ReadToEnd();
```